# splitting strings with , space, ordinal number and commas

Tags: java, string, split

Tuesday, 7th of May 2013

splitting this I want to have 7, "may" and 2013, what if the day is 1st 2nd and 3rd day of the month?

Comment: i dont know how to use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use first split and then substring to get date like below.

```
    String str ="Tuesday, 1st of May 2013";
    String arr[] = str.split(" ");
    String date = arr[1].substring(0,arr[1].length()-2);
    String month = arr[3];
    String year = arr[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Approach:

1. Break the text into 5 sub strings using "Space"
   Sub 1 gives you "tuesday"
   Sub 2 gives you date- extract only number from this text
   Sub 3 gives "of" - discard as you dont neeed it
   Sub 4 gives you Month name
   Sub 5 gives you year.

Other approach:

if this is the date that you are getting, then you can use functions of date class to get day, month and year of the date.

Answer (score 0):

If your date string keeps the same pattern you could use something along the lines of:

```
    String pattern = "\\w+,\\s(\\d+).+of\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\d{4})";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher("Tuesday, 7th of May 2013");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Day: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Month: " + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("Year: " + m.group(3));
    }
```